# DateField selectedDate always returns null

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, mxml

I have an `MXML` component which I'm using to create a popup. In this component i have a `DateField` with id `fromDate`and format string as `DD.MM.YYYY` when I'm trying to set the date as

```
formDate.text = "17.05.2016";
```

and then try to access the date as

```
fromDate.selectedDate; //this is returning null
```

When I'm trying to set the date in date field in the same way in the main mxml document it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

> When I'm trying to set the date in date field in the same way in the main mxml document it is working fine.

This is not equivalent to setting the `.text` property programmatically which usually does not trigger an input event in the view and thus not a change event in the model.